# How to align text outside of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to make a barplot like the figure a of this [one](https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature25501/MediaObjects/41586_2018_Article_BFnature25501_Fig6_ESM.jpg?as=webp) that I found in a publication with something like a table tab showing some information outside the plot using `ggplot`. I found [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-text-outside-of-ggplot/21950/3) general approach of adding text outside of a plot using `gridExtra`.

However, my question is how to align the height of each row of the table tab to each bar of the barplot so they match?

Here is an example. I wanted to add the `note` as a table tab on the right of the barplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <-  data.frame(Model = c("Datsun 710","Duster 360","Hornet 4 Drive","Hornet 
                             Sportabout","Mazda RX4 Wag","Merc 230","Merc 240D","Valiant"),
                  logFC = c(1.879,1.552,1.360,1.108,-2.407,-2.416,-2.670,-3.061),
                  Note = c("ModelA","ModelB","ModelC","ModelD","ModelE","ModelF","ModelG","ModelH"))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Model, logFC)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_bw() +
        ggtitle("Data for cars") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, hjust = 0.5))

tab <- as.data.frame(
       c(Note = df$Note))

rownames(tab) <- NULL

p_tab <- tableGrob(unname(tab))

grid.arrange(plot, p_tab, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: It would be easier to extend the margin of the plot and use `geom_text`, keep it all in `ggplot` with the coordinate system already established.

Comment: @Gregor, you are absolutely right. I got inspired. I am posting it in the answer.

Comment: Love to see it when people post answers to their own questions!

Answer (score 1):

Per Gregor's comment, this works for me:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Model, logFC, label=Note)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Data for cars") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, hjust = 0.5))+
  geom_text(y = 3, 
            hjust = 0,
            size = 5) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,10,1,1), "lines"),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```